# WebLogic 12.2.1 NullPointerException on deploy

Tags: oracle, servlets, netbeans, weblogic

I'm developing a REST application using WebLogic 12.2.1 and NetBeans.

Inside NetBeans, I'm using the local host and deploying without problems.

When I use the Orcacle WebLogic admin tool, the system throws a NullPointerException.

Here is the ApplicationConfig:

```
import com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

/**
 *
 * @author Leandro.Tietbohl
 */
@ApplicationPath("service")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        register(GensonJsonConverter.class);
        packages("br.com.sicredi.programassociais.rest.service");
    }
}
```

Here is the weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <debug>true</debug>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <context-root>/sicredi-programas-sociais-rest</context-root>

    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>com.owlike.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ApplicationConfig</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.sicredi.programassociais.rest.service.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            60
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

> weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: Apps tool failure: Check
>   nested exception for details <18/04/2018 14h02min06s BRT> 
>         at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.handleStateChangeException(FlowDriver.java:55)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:38)
>     at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:146)
>     at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)  at
>   weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)   at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:158)   at
>   weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:94)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:58)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:186)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createLazyDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:160)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.inspect(SessionHelper.java:777)
>     at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow$2.execute(Flow.java:530)
>     at
>   com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5636)
>     at
>   com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow.appSelected(Flow.java:528)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116)
>     at
>   com.bea.console.internal.ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
>     at
>   com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.process(ConsoleActionServlet.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
>     at
>   com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.doGet(ConsoleActionServlet.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199)
>     at
>   org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1129)
>     at
>   com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.framework.internal.PageFlowUtilsBeehiveDelegate.strutsLookupInternal(PageFlowUtilsBeehiveDelegate.java:43)
>     at
>   com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.framework.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:108)
>     at
>   com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:707)
>     at
>   com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.processActionInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:141)
>     at
>   com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.PageFlowStubImpl.processAction(PageFlowStubImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   com.bea.portlet.adapter.NetuiActionHandler.raiseScopedAction(NetuiActionHandler.java:111)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:181)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:167)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.handlePostbackData(NetuiContent.java:225)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$2.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:180)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:324)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:130)
>     at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
>     at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
>     at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
>     at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runInbound(Lifecycle.java:184)   at
>   com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:159)   at
>   com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:465)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:219)
>     at
>   com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:275)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:125)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>     at com.bea.console.internal.ParamFilter.doFilter(ParamFilter.java:38)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
>     at
>   weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
>     at
>   weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   weblogic.jaxrs.server.extension.JaxRsContainerInitializer.createApplicationBaseUriForServletMappings(JaxRsContainerInitializer.java:405)
>     at
>   weblogic.jaxrs.server.extension.JaxRsContainerInitializer.createRestWebserviceDescriptionBeanForServlet(JaxRsContainerInitializer.java:400)
>     at
>   weblogic.jaxrs.server.extension.JaxRsContainerInitializer.addServletWithExistingRegistration(JaxRsContainerInitializer.java:223)
>     at
>   weblogic.jaxrs.server.extension.JaxRsContainerInitializer.initialize(JaxRsContainerInitializer.java:102)
>     at
>   weblogic.jaxrs.server.extension.JaxRsToolsModuleExtension.merge(JaxRsToolsModuleExtension.java:58)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleMergeFlow.proecessModule(SingleModuleMergeFlow.java:33)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleFlow.compile(SingleModuleFlow.java:64)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
>     at weblogic.application.compiler.BaseMerger.merge(BaseMerger.java:20)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:75)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:40)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
>     ... 116 more

Comment: The problem seems to be related to Genson library

Comment: there must be another stacktrace showing the root cause. That stacktrace is the one showing WLS layers (admin console, compiler). Try compile it with "appc"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is relative to the method *createApplicationBaseUriForServletMappings* visible in the stacktrace. The null-pointer is due to a missing mapping definition.

No mappings is defined in the *web.xml* file for the **ApplicationConfig** servlet. Il you add a mapping, this should work fine.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ApplicationConfig</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/yourPathHere</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```